# Two-electron integral algorithm

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I am writing a molecular integral code from scratch. Right now [my code](https://github.com/Melisius/SlowQuant/tree/35c452a970a4cfaf79db44220c97f879a4757bf9/slowquant/molecularintegrals) have the following structure:

```
loop over shellpair ab:
    loop over shellpair cd:
        loop over primitive ij in ab:
            calculate E_ij
            loop over primitive kl in cd:
                calculate E_kl
                calculate R_ij_kl
                calculate V_ab_cd_ij_kl
        contract V_ab_cd_ij_kl to V_ab_cd
```

The above pseudo-code have alot of implicit notation, so let me explain what it means before asking my question.

E_ij and E_kl is the expansions coefficients from the McMurchie Davidson scheme. 
R_ij_kl is the Hermite integrals also used in the Mcmurchie Davidson scheme.
V_ab_cd_ij_kl is the cartesian integrals found by (note the equations below are not strictly correct):

$$V_{ab,cd,ij,kl}=\sum E_{kl}\sum E_{ij} R_{ij,kl}$$

And V_ab_cd is the contraction of the primitive to the basisfunction:

$$V_{ab,cd}=\sum_i\sum_j\sum_k\sum_l c_ic_jc_kc_lV_{ab,cd,ij,kl}$$

When calculating integrals of higher angular momentum (above $0$), I make sure to reuse common elements in E and R. I.e. when doing p-type integrals px, py and pz have the first element in common, and it is only calculated once in the recurrence relations of the McMurchie Davidson scheme.

For my implementation of the above pseudo-code even the (ss|ss) integrals are very slow. When doing benenze with 6-31G the (ss|ss) integrals uses 2.5 seconds, which is more than can be justified by the use of Python (accelerated with Numba) instead of a compiled language. I have thought about rearranging and saving more intermidiates in memory, i.e. doing something like:

```
 loop over shellpair ab:
    calculate E_ab (Here E_ab means all E_ij saved in memory)
    loop over shellpair cd:
        calculate E_cd (Here E_ab means all E_kl saved in memory)
        loop over primitive ij in ab:
            loop over primitive kl in cd:
                calculate R_ij_kl
                calculate V_ab_cd_ij_kl
        contract V_ab_cd_ij_kl to V_ab_cd
```

In the above by calculating E_ab and E_cd, recomputation of E_ij and E_kl is avoided. At this point I know that I lag some expertise in knowing what is worth it compared to memory usage.

**My question is know, what is a proper way of implementing molecular integrals with regard of what intermediates to keep at which points.** (I know thing like vertical recurrence relations exist, but these will for obvious reasons not speed on my (ss|ss) integrals).

Comment: Semi-related, have you thought about using a lookup table for the Boys function? Your solution is probably faster than the analytic one, but some experts once told me about 30% of the time in calculating (ss|ss) is spent there.

Comment: Thanks for your observation.
I have thought about making my Boys function faster through look up tabels as  you suggest. This is also the recommended method in Molecular Electronic-Structure Theory.
I think that right now I am mostly concerned about figuring out how I want the broad structure of the code.

Comment: I agree. As far as I know, the way the Boys function is incorporated never changes; it’s just called as a function, as you do, so any performance improvements are localized.

Comment: @user1271772 Being slow is not the intention, but probably poking fun at the fact that being fast enough for practical computation is very difficult. Avoiding recomputation of intermediates is the primary form of reducing the number of FLOPs, since you can't change the scaling complexity.

Comment: I was trying to be constructive @pentavalentcarbon. I believe that not repeating these integrals will be counter-productive towards the goal of making the program slow. Otherwise, would this be helpful? http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/notes/permsymm/permsymm.pdf

Comment: @user1271772 In that case I apologize. That document is not actually helpful because it is too high-level; using an analogy, it's like comparing Python with C that includes assembly in some places. The starting place is usually https://rsc.anu.edu.au/~pgill/papers/045Review.pdf, and in particular the section on "drivers". This is difficult because your intermediate is stored in a fixed-dimension Fortran array meant to behave as a hash table, where the key is an integer formed from basis set and shell pair info. In Python, a dictionary avoids some of that.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon: By "too high level" do you mean that the notes were talking about something too trivial (symmetry relations), whereas the OP is asking about some more niddy-griddy details to squeeze in even better performance?

Comment: @user1271772 Yes, exactly.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon: I thought the purpose was to build a program that is slow. However, perhaps the part that I missed, is that he wants this particular part to be done at decent speed.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon  rsc.anu.edu.au/~pgill/papers/045Review.pdf seem very useful, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately writing an integral code with decent performance is rather difficult. I also did it once for a hobby project and I'm still not overall satisfied. What I found helpful back then was the following thesis https://www.duo.uio.no/handle/10852/12863 (chapter 4). A more general remark: Low angular momenta integrals like (ss|ss) but also (ps|ss) carry some overhead. There are many inner loops running basicly from 0 to 0 or 0 to 1, which slows down. Many QM codes therefore use special routines to handle this integral classes, where they unrolled this loops.

Comment: Also semi-related: One possible solution to avoid double evaluation is to wrap a cache around your functions.  This can be implemented very easily with [@functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), for Python2 this is provided by [functools32](https://pypi.org/project/functools32/).

Comment: You may wish to read about the PRISM algorithm (I believe the original paper is with Pople and M. Head-Gordon). This is the algorithm which is commonly used in the big software packages as it offers a trade-off between storage of certain expensive integrals and reuse of the vertical recursion relations for cheaper (one-electron) integrals.

Comment: @ErikKjellgren this question seems related to a recent one: https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/62/5. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: @ErikKjellgren here's another one you should see: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4478/5

Answer (score 4):

There are many things to consider and improve your code. Many components
in an ab initio electronic structure calculations need supervision to achieve a
good performance. I am no expert on those calculations, but I will point you to some ideas and references. On the theoretical side, you could calculate E_ab for all shell pairs first. For more clarification on the order of operations and their scaling look at
Figure 3 in [Multi-electron integrals](https://doi.org/10.1002/wcms.78). The article is written by a well-recognized researcher in the field that wrote a monumental book where you can find all needed expressions.

On the computational side, I would say that maybe Numba is not able to optimize your code. Writing it with Numba is not a guarantee of speed. I just took a glimpse at the code and, without going deep in the code, I saw many `if` statements. Only a straightforward observation. As general advice, it is all about how data is moved
and the flow of operations. Avoid allocations, try to rewrite as much as possible.
Profile your code to find the bottlenecks. Try to write it as vector or matrix operations to be able to use the large registers of the processor. There are many tricks to do these operations fast, but sadly they are buried elsewhere.

I would like to end with a reference to the recent literature on the topic. I just came up with an article that I managed to find again now: [Fast Evaluation of Two-Center Integrals over Gaussian Charge Distributions and Gaussian Orbitals with General Interaction Kernels](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.9b01296).